# After resizing view inside UIScrollView, the scroll view does not know it changed

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I resized the view that I put into a UIScrollView, but the scroll view does not know that the size changed.

So, I tried removing the view and re-adding it to the UIScrollView, but that did not help.

How can I convince the UIScrollView that its contents have changed size?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try resetting `@property(nonatomic) CGSize contentSize` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you remember to set the content size of the UIScrollView (using `[scrollview setContentSize:]`) to the new size? The scroll view doesn't figure it out on its own, you have to tell it what the size of its content is.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I did forget that and when I did it, it fix the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the scrollview is a subview of another view and you resized that view (the parent of the scrollview) the scrollview will not actually get resized unless you have set [autoresizesSubviews](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizesSubviews) property of the parent view.  You will also have to set the [autoresizingMask](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask) of the scrollview as well.

If you prefer to manually layout the subviews (still assuming the scroll view is a subview of some parent view), you can implement [layoutSubviews](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews) in the parent view to change the size/position of the subviews when the size of the parent view changes.